# 404 error when i call webservice in java

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I have created a jersey web-service in Java and I have the following issue:
When I run the project in my localhost apache tomcat server, I call it with the URL localhost:8080/api/verify? and I haven't any problem.
When I upload it in my web-hosting and I call it with URL myDomainName/api/verify? I get 404 error.
Does anyone know why it's happened? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: A 404 error appears when a page does not exist. Make sure you typing the correct URL or that the file exists..

Comment: Can you please tell if the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your web service to be deployed and successfully started (on **80** port).
2. Check your hosting security settings to allow access to **/api/***.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS server, your firewall, and your load balancer to make sure they are pointing to your app.

Verify if you are using http or https.

Edited to add:  make sure your default tomcat port 8080 is there in the load balancer (if you have one).  If you don't have one yet try http://yourDomainName:8080/api/verify and see if that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please try what others have suggested and also check if your domain name (myDomainName) is the correct one. If you have packed your projected as a war check the name of the generated folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses.

The problem was resolved by my web hosting support.
The solution was the following:
He changed the mappings (mod jk tomcat connector ) from *.jsp to /* to fix the issue.